# Basic encryption algorithms

Tags: algorithm, encryption, cryptography

I need to know some simple encryption algorithms. I need at least 10 algorithms to demonstrate basic cryptology. I'm going to implement it in a program (that should be my problem).

What I want is just the algorithm, very simple ones more like the level of simplicity in the ROT13 algorithm (this is not included).

Comment: I like double ROT-13.  Twice as secure as regular ROT-13.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipher — in particular, classical ciphers.

Comment: yes but you have to make a program that demonstrate the algorithm... i found some algorithms but i need 10 more... i just need the algo.

Comment: @Cat plus Plus, found the list of classical chipers... this is what i need...

Comment: @CatPlusPlus maybe post the list as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adapt classical algorithms to use bytes instead of letters: Caesar, Monoalphabetic substitution, Vigenère, Playfair, Four Square for example.  The extension from 26 (or 36) characters to 256 byte values is pretty much obvious in those cases.

The One Time Pad (i.e. XOR) is extremely simple to program.

Of the modern computer cyphers only RC4 could really be described as simple to program.

Comment: using bytes instead of letter is a pretty good idea... ill try that out.. thanks for the answer. although classic ciphers alone is enough for me...

Answer (score 0):

DES: http://orlingrabbe.com/des.htm
You could class triple DES as it's own algorithm too.

AES - http://www.scribd.com/api_user_11797_Tanmoy%20Sen%20Gupta/d/7107279-The-AES-Algorithm

Blowfish - www.schneier.com/blowfish-download.html

A very basic Xor is a possibility too if you run out of ideas.

Comment: I already found that encryption algorithms.... but, that is just too complicated for me. but thanks for the links...

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that AES and DES are too difficult to implement. But these are not encryption algorithms -- they are blockciphers, and are fairly useless by themselves. Modern encryption algorithms are typically built on top of blockciphers.

If your instructor let's you use someone else's AES implementation, you can use it to build a variety of encryption algorithms, such as counter mode or cipher-block chaining. These algorithms should be fairly straight-forward to implement.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this book "the codebook by Simon Singh". It will help you to understand encryption algorithms easily. you can download it here.
http://simonsingh.net/cryptography/crypto-cd-rom/